# Can I set up two Samsung monitors to my mac book air mid 2012?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Mac Book Air mid 2012 and want to connect two Samsung monitors- I have one through the thunderbolt and the other through the USB port but it is not working properly

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't working properly?

Comment: @jamie, if my answer answers your question, please mark it so.  Thanks.

Comment: @jamie, did this resolve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Can I set up two Samsung monitors to my mac book air mid 2012?

**No.**

USB does not generally have the bandwidth for video data.

https://support.apple.com/kb/sp650?locale=en_US

This MacBook Air only additional supports one display via the thunderbolt port.

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an
>   external display, both at millions of colors